# Как сделать такой слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать такой слайдер? 
Он растягивается на всю ширину экрана, активная картинка видна полностью, а те которые слева и справа видны не полностью.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно все решение, или только сама идея, что и как? Если не важно понимание, то делайте как на ссылке ув. @teran

Comment: взять какой-нибудь slick и сделать http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ - Center mode

Comment: @teran, спасибо, воспользуюсь